# Best component to show info-text with?

Tags: c#, user-interface

I am to have a label/textfield with some information. Problem is that a RichTextField will change to a grey color when inactive so the user cannot edit the information, and the label's text will not linebreak with the resizing of the window. What is the best approach to show text that will follow the size of the parent container, like a div in html.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use rich text and set readonly to true rather than setting enabled to false.